# How can I prevent my gameobject from rotating all the time when trying to move it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, angle

So I have a gameobject (my player) which moves via a joystick. Without the rotating code below my player moves well and smooth, but after I put the rotating code below the gameobject rotates all the time (360 degrees) when I try to move it.

My aim is to rotate the player around a specific angle when the player turns.

```
void Update()
{
    // move
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * leftController.GetTouchPosition.y * Time.deltaTime * speedMovements) +
        (transform.right * leftController.GetTouchPosition.x * Time.deltaTime * speedMovements) );

    //rotate 
    double rad = Mathf.Atan2(leftController.GetTouchPosition.y, leftController.GetTouchPosition.x); // In radians
    double deg = rad * (180 / System.Math.PI);
    transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, (float) deg);
}
```

Comment: In your last line of code . 
`transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up , Time.deltaTime * (float) deg);`

Shouldn't it be more like this?

Comment: @EmreE well its a little better. now.but the problem now is that when i have for example my joystick at upper left position my player moves at that position and during that it rotates all the time because of every frame. What I want is that i walk normal to a position and there should be only ONE rotation for each angle. it rotates 360 when I move...

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I got your question right I think you're using the wrong function.

To me, RotateAround would be better for a planet orbit for example (perpetual movement)

If you just want to rotate the player in a given direction and stop when it's done, you should try these functions instead :

- Transform.LookAt
- Quaternion.LookRotation
- Quaternion.RotateTowards
- Quaternion.Slerp